# Exo Player: How to allow our video stream urls to be played only by our apps?

Tags: android, authentication, video, header, exoplayer

We have video content hosted on our server and these video stream urls can be played from any where
Ex:

1. From our http://ourwebsite.com using video player
2. From our android app using exo player
3. From any other website using video player
4. From any other android app using exo player

Now we want to block our video streams to be played for #3 and #4

#3 can be handled using Cross Origin Resource Sharing(CORS) mechanism which uses  **Origin** and **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** as request and response headers resp..

We are unable to find a solution for native exoplayer on android. Would like to know if there is a way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much effort you want to take and how important it is not to have the streams copied there are different approaches you can take:

- you can require user login and/or a session token to be used to access the content for playback. The token would typically be included in the player request for playback.
- You could encrypt the content using a clear key system, or using your own key which you share with valid users separately.
- You could encrypt the content using DRM for the encryption and for secure key sharing.

Most commercial streaming providers will use both user authentication and DRM.

If you want to avoid a commercial DRM, clear key schemes are not as secure but will deter many casual unauthorised users:

- DASH Clearkey: https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/ClearKey-Content-Protection
- HLS AES: you can see some examples at the end of this spec: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-hls-rfc8216bis-02#page-39